# .Net 6.0 BackgroundService.ExecuteAsync stoppingToken/Exception weirdness

Tags: .net

I'm trying to use the basic Worker template in .Net 6. With the default implementation when I press Ctrl-C to exit, the code after the while loop in ExecuteAsync is never hit. I added the exception handling, and sure enough as soon as I press Ctrl-C I get the exception which logs the message "Execute Cancelled".  What's bizarre is that before I added the exception handling code the app exited "cleanly," ie no exception was shown in the console. Now that he code is there, right after I see the log message it also shows an exception, as if I hadn't caught it.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await Task.Yield();

            try
            {
                while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation($"Worker running at: {DateTimeOffset.Now} / Cancel: {stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested}");
                    await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
                }
// THIS CODE NEVER EXECUTES
                _logger.LogInformation("Execution ended. Cancelation token cancelled = {IsCancellationRequested}",stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning(ex, "Execution Cancelled");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandeled exception. Execution Stopping");
            }
        }

    }
```

Output w/ Exception Handling:

```
info: WorkerService1.Worker[0]
      Worker running at: 6/6/2023 1:10:08 PM -04:00 / Cancel: False
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\jangi\source\repos\WorkerService1
info: WorkerService1.Worker[0]
      Worker running at: 6/6/2023 1:10:09 PM -04:00 / Cancel: False
info: WorkerService1.Worker[0]
      Worker running at: 6/6/2023 1:10:10 PM -04:00 / Cancel: False
info: WorkerService1.Worker[0]
      Worker running at: 6/6/2023 1:10:11 PM -04:00 / Cancel: False
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
warn: WorkerService1.Worker[0]
      Execution Cancelled
      System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
         at WorkerService1.Worker.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) in C:\Users\jangi\source\repos\WorkerService1\Worker.cs:line 23
```

Output without Exception Handling:

```
info: WorkerService1.Worker[0]
      Worker running at: 6/6/2023 1:14:30 PM -04:00 / Cancel: False
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\jangi\source\repos\WorkerService1
info: WorkerService1.Worker[0]
      Worker running at: 6/6/2023 1:14:31 PM -04:00 / Cancel: False
info: WorkerService1.Worker[0]
      Worker running at: 6/6/2023 1:14:32 PM -04:00 / Cancel: False
info: WorkerService1.Worker[0]
      Worker running at: 6/6/2023 1:14:33 PM -04:00 / Cancel: False
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
```

I've been all over the web and every other example I can find shows different behavior than what I'm seeing.

Comment: `right after I see the log message it also shows an exception, as if I hadn't caught it.` The log message includes the exception because your code is passing the exception to the logger. The exception message is part of the log message, not after it.

Comment: Of course... thanks.  I've been banging my head against this for awhile now and tried so many combinations that I wasn't even paying attention to that.  Since I never even see an exception when I don't catch it, I'm assuming Host is swallowing it.

Comment: Exceptions from background services are ignored. By the base class, I believe.

Comment: So it seems that if I need to run some 3rd party code as a background service the only way I can effectively stop it is to use Task.Delay with that stoppingtoken, and catch the taskcancelled exception to stop the service?  The 3rd party code does not accept a token, I need to call a stop method.  And if it's going to take longer than 5 seconds to process that I have to mess with the shutdowntimer as well.  Seems kinda clunky overall unless I'm missing something.

Comment: That's kind of roundabout but it would technically work. I'd prefer just registering `Stop` with the cancellation token instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With the default implementation when I press Ctrl-C to exit, the code after the while loop in ExecuteAsync is never hit.

Yes, an `OperationCanceledException` (or derived type) would be thrown. This is normal when observing cancellation tokens.

> I added the exception handling, and sure enough as soon as I press Ctrl-C I get the exception which logs the message "Execute Cancelled". What's bizarre is that before I added the exception handling code the app exited "cleanly," ie no exception was shown in the console. Now that he code is there, right after I see the log message it also shows an exception, as if I hadn't caught it.

The log message includes the exception because your code is passing the exception to the logger. The exception message is part of the log message, not after it.

The exception is silently swallowed regardless of the logging code. This is one of the [gotchas of `BackgroundService`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-silent-failure.html) that I describe on my blog.

Comment: That blog is fantastic, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a `Task.Delay` using a canceled token.

```
await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
```

[Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-task-delay(system-timespan-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) throws `TaskCanceledException` when the token is canceled.